# How to re-write a loop of a list of dicts using enumerate?

Tags: python, loops

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
hashed_data = [
    {'EffectiveDate': '1981-03-90', 'TimeSeriesValue': 100, 'IRR': 0.34},
    {'EffectiveDate': '1981-04-90', 'TimeSeriesValue': None, 'IRR': 0.84},
    {'EffectiveDate': '1981-05-90', 'TimeSeriesValue': None, 'IRR': 0.54},
    {'EffectiveDate': '1981-06-90', 'TimeSeriesValue': None, 'IRR': 0.31}
]
```

I wrote a method to calculate the `TimeSeriesValue`, formula is as follows:

`timeseriesValue = (previous timeseriesValue  * IRR) + pervious timeseriesValue`

```
    for index in (0, len(hashed_data) - 1):
        hashed_data[index + 1]['TimeSeriesValue'] = \
            (hashed_data[index + 1]['IRR'] * hashed_data[index]['TimeSeriesValue']) + \
            hashed_data[index]['TimeSeriesValue']
```

I was told there was a more pythonic way of writing this, using `enumerate`

I tried this:

```
for i, item in enumerate(hashed_data):
  hashed_data[i+1]['TimeSeriesValue'] = (hashed_data[i+1]['IRR'] * hashed_data[i]['TimeSeriesValue']) + hashed_data[i]['TimeSeriesValue']
```

But the index gets out of range once it reaches the end of the loop. How can I rewrite my original loop?

Comment: You can start your `enumerate` at 1 and use `i-1` in the loop.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think using `enumerate` is appropriate since this is a fairly recursive problem in nature.

Comment: Would you suggest to sticking to the original for loop?

Comment: I'd organize the code completely differently, to be honest.

Comment: Uff, I'm an intern here. How would you re-organize the code yourself? Seems like everyone has their own way to skin a cat here. I'm currently making sure the code works, then thinking what's the best way to re-write it or make it more "pythonic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use any indices. What you want to do is: given an element, update its value based on the values of its previous element. You can do this if you have references to the element `n` and the element `n+1`. In Python, this can be achieved with a `zip` of an iterable and itself shifted:

```
>>> hashed_data = [
...     {'EffectiveDate': '1981-03-90', 'TimeSeriesValue': 100, 'IRR': 0.34},
...     {'EffectiveDate': '1981-04-90', 'TimeSeriesValue': None, 'IRR': 0.84},
...     {'EffectiveDate': '1981-05-90', 'TimeSeriesValue': None, 'IRR': 0.54},
...     {'EffectiveDate': '1981-06-90', 'TimeSeriesValue': None, 'IRR': 0.31}
... ]
>>>
>>> for e_prev, e in zip(hashed_data, hashed_data[1:]):
...     e['TimeSeriesValue'] = ( e_prev['TimeSeriesValue'] * e_prev['IRR'] ) + e_prev['TimeSeriesValue']
...
>>> hashed_data
[{'EffectiveDate': '1981-03-90', 'TimeSeriesValue': 100, 'IRR': 0.34}, {'EffectiveDate': '1981-04-90', 'TimeSeriesValue': 134.0, 'IRR': 0.84}, {'EffectiveDate': '1981-05-90', 'TimeSeriesValue': 246.56, 'IRR': 0.54}, {'EffectiveDate': '1981-06-90', 'TimeSeriesValue': 379.7024, 'IRR': 0.31}]
```